# Error when trying to run snap install from ubuntu on docker

Tags: snap, docker

I'm getting the following error when trying to run simple snap test

```
snap install hello
```

Get the following error:

main.go:239: WARNING: cannot create syslog logger
error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/hello: dial unix /run/snapd-snap.socket: connect: no such file or directory

Comment: Have you made any progress with this? I have the same issue. If you could list the docker image you're using that would be great. I've not been able to get it to work with any `ubuntu:16.04` images.

Comment: See also this thread on Snapcraft's mailing list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/snapcraft/2017-February/003013.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to at least have `snapd` running in the container for a `snap` install to work as the `snap` command mostly sends restful messages to `snapd` to get things done.

Look at the service unit for `snapd` to see the parameters and environment setup required to run.

PS: This might get installation working, but the next hurdle will be stacking security profiles from `docker` and `snapd`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I've started looking at some docker images that have systemd running.

Answer (score 0):

try `snap install hello-world` and not just `hello`.

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ snap list
Name         Version     Rev   Developer   Notes
core         16-2.29.3   3440  canonical   core
docker       17.06.1-ce  171   docker-inc  -
hello-world  6.3         27    canonical   -
ubuntu-make  master      116   didrocks    classic
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 17.10
Release:    17.10
Codename:   artful
thufir@dur:~$
```

also, pls post the output for `snap list`.